# Is there a LINQ-oriented method to quicky evaluate nested lists in dictionaries

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have a dictionary constructed like this:

```
Dictionary<string, List<MyObject>>
```

And my object has an integer value as one of its properties:

```
public class MyObject 
{
  public int number {get; set;}
}
```

How would I construct a LINQ-oriented query to evaluate the average `number` for each `Key` in the dictionary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your needs

```
var results = dict.Select(
   x => new
           {
              x.Key,
              avg = x.Value.Average(y => y.number)
           });
```

Or if you want your results in a dictionary

```
var results = dict.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value.Average(y => y.number));
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I somehow missed that dictionaries were actually enumerable already :/ +1

Comment: I understand. By the way your version is now better but still wrong because the second selector takes the value as a parameter

Answer (score 1):

Because dictionaries are enumerables, your request can be accomplished in a straightforward and natural manner

```
 var averages = dictionary
     .ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value.Average(e => e.number));
```

Answer (score 1):

[Demo on dotnet fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/l3p469)

You can use [`Average`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.average?view=netframework-4.8) to achieve it.

```
var data = new Dictionary<string, List<MyObject>>();
data.Add("1", new List<MyObject> { new MyObject { number = 1 }, new MyObject { number = 2 }, new MyObject { number = 3 }});
data.Add("2", new List<MyObject> { new MyObject { number = 4 }, new MyObject { number = 5 }, new MyObject { number = 6 }});

var result = data.Select(p => new { p.Key, Average = p.Value.Average(n => n.number) });
```